# Execution time between functions with & without arguments C/C++

Tags: c++, c, function, execution-time

I'd just like to ask what's the difference in execution time when:

a) We have variables declared in `main()` and send them in functions using arguments

b) We have global variables and access them directly from functions with no arguments

The thing is I started writing few aps and just saw a few discussions about this, but I haven't yet written any application that makes the difference bigger then few ms.

Comment: These are great questions from an academic point of view. But please don't consider any optimization before you have a problem, and then measure where it is and fix only what causes the problem. Besides making code impossible to maintain, most human 'optimizations' even make the application slower, because you are accidentally disabling all sorts of compiler optimizations.

Comment: I know one programmer who did some embedded work int eh early '90s.  Back then, they passed everything in global variables, but if I understand correctly that was to avoid having the stack grow at all (avoid smashing the stack) and had nothing to do with relative performance.  Of course, things have changed in the last 20 years.

Comment: I asked because on college we are creating automate simulators where user defines the automate with pure input and then the program makes the simulation and gives the output. So far I've been using mostly global variables filled with info from the user and passed only what was necessary in form of arguments. I've asked myself if that's a good way since we did all functions before ( in beginners class ) with passing arguments. All of my simulations are written in C++ with around 400-500 lines of code, but they all execute within 1-1.5 sec depending on how complex was the input.

Comment: Every programmer I've met -- including myself -- went through a phase where they (1) could think of multiple approaches to a problem but could not decide which to use, and resolved to get rid of emotion and choose on numbers alone; and (2) couldn't measure anything except speed, so chose the solution based entirely on which approach was faster.  This is basically always the wrong thing to do.  You almost never need the fastest solution to a problem: instead you want the most maintainable, clearest, most straightforward solution.

Comment: Personally, the very first thing I would recommend for your simulator would be to group your global variables into classes.  For instance, if you have three variables that affect how you format your log messages, put them into a `Log_message_config` class, create one (global) instance of that class and set its member variables accordingly.  Then ask yourself if you can clean things up more, if individual `_config` classes can be changed to parameters passed to functions, etc.

Comment: I do have variables grouped in variables, depending on when I'm using them, for instance my variables that contain input data are defined in header file along with classes, while other variables that I use for temporary strings or anything else are within their own classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Passing parameters to function involves *usually* one of two assembler instructions: `push param` (and later `pop param`) or `mov ax, param`. Since processor is able to do (a lot) more in a second, such "optimization" mostly probably will go unnoticed (a few ms on the whole program is below the error margin)

Using global variables in the place of function parameters will cause a huge mess in the code with almost unnoticeable or possibly no performance gain.

Comment: I'm aware how stack works, so in bigger programs there isn't much of a difference between those 2 ?

Comment: There shouldn't be much of a big difference. Especially that optimizer very often modifies the code internally such that a variable is made global or even disappears at all. Modern compiler optimizers are really a miracle-doers.

Comment: @spook parameters are written to stack with push or mov, but they're rarely read from stack with pop because there normally is a return address on top of the arguments. The arguments are read from stack like normal local variables, just different offset.

Comment: @lego You're right; however regarding to the question, passing parameters involves both push and pop for each one (unless passed by the register), while using global variables involves no such operations. Modified the answer to be precise though.

Comment: @Spook No, passing parameters does *not* have to involve `pop` at all. The single `leave` instruction can be used to restore `esp` from `ebp` and remove the saved `ebp` from the stack. It's a single-byte opcode, `C9`.

Comment: @AndrewMedico Didn't know that. So passing parameters is pratically as fast as a single push for each parameter, right? I wouldn't worry much about performance here.

Answer (score 4):

All of this depends on what CPU and compiler that are used.

When you pass a parameter to a function, one of the following could happen:

- The parameter is stored in a CPU register. This is very efficient.
- The parameter is stored on the stack. This is the most common. It involves some minor overhead of pushing/popping the parameter to/from the stack when the function is started/finished.
- The parameter isn't a new variable at all. Instead, the compiler inlines the function and uses the original variable for modifications. This is about as efficient as you can get.

Using a global variable is will be ever so slightly faster than using the stack. It will unlikley be faster than using a CPU register: inside the function the value might need to be loaded into such a register before calculations anyhow.

It should be noted we are talking about a few CPU ticks here and there.

My advise:

- You should never attempt any kind of manual optimizations unless you have in-depth hardware knowledge of the specific CPU used. If you have no such knowledge, the compiler will optimize the code better than you do in 99% of the cases. Because the compiler port was most likely written by an expert of the given system. The compiler also knows the overall performance picture, which the programmer does not, so the compiler is more suitable for doing the optimization.
- You should never attempt any kind of manual optimization unless you have actually performed formal benchmarking and found a bottleneck in the program.
- Global variables are incredibly bad and dangerous to use. They lead to spaghetti code and they are not thread-safe.
- If you are writing some kind of high-end desktop application, such as PC programs or phone apps, then using global variables to increase performance is *complete nonsense*. You are on a system which has non-existent real-time performance to begin with! At any given time, your OS might decide to chew up many billions of CPU ticks while giving your program the finger. So don't go chasing 1 or 2 CPU ticks.
- These kind of manual optimizations only make sense if you are developing embedded systems applications that are very close to the hardware, and at the same time have hard real-time requirements.

Answer (score 2):

Stack operations are very efficient, and they are made even more efficient because the stack is likely to be in cache memory. That could make using the stack even faster than not using it.

Comment: Stack operations are not as efficient as using registers.  In order to get something from the stack, you need to load a register with the address of the stack frame, the dereference the address plus offset.  This step is eliminated when values are passed in a register.

Answer (score 2):

Expect parameter passed variables to be a lot faster than global variables. In Modern ABIs, function parameters are passed mostly using CPU registers which are immediately available to the CPU.

Global variables must be read from (static) memory. Worse than that, static memory is allocated on its own memory page, which is generally far from your stack (or heap) memory. This means that cache misses are  more likely which in turn means that access can consume a large number of CPU cycles.

Obviously this depends a lot on your usage patterns.